# C++ Inheritance Problem leads to segmentation fault

Tags: c++

Here is some sample code to illustrate the problem I am having.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Foo
{
    public:
        Foo(int x)
        { m_x = x; }
        int getX()
        { return m_x; }
    private:
        int m_x;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
    public:
        Bar(int x) : Foo(x)
        {}
        //some other stuff
};

int main()
{
    Bar* bar = new Bar(5);
    cout<<bar->getX()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I have a large project that I am working on and I have a similar situation to above. When bar->getX() is called the this pointer is 0x0 causing a segmentation fault. I have tried copping the getX function to the Bar class but this does not fix the problem, the this pointer is still 0x0. Any ideas? I have no idea how to google for this, only found people having problems with virtual functions.

ps. This sample works.

## EDIT:

```
std::cout<<m_engine<<std::endl;
focus_x = m_engine->getX();
```

The output is:0x2e6d763638667858 (not NULL), so that is not the problem...

Comment: I looked through the code trying to find a problem, and then noticed your comment at the bottom about this sample working.  It will be easier if you post the code which doesn't work, and we can help you figure out the problem with it.

Comment: this could happen only if 'new' fails AND you are somehow using the non throwing version of new

Comment: @Chubsdad - for 'new' to fail in the example above, you'd have to be using a computer with *very* limited resources.

Comment: @LeopardSkinPillBoxHat: I guess it is possible to use a non-throwing version of new for some older compilers.

Comment: @Chubsdad - my point was that there is a very small amount of memory being allocated above.  Even if we were using a non-throwing version of `new`, what's the likelihood of `new` failing to allocate the insignificant amount of memory in that program?

Comment: I can't possibly put the entire code here, it is too complex, more info added above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess, from your edit, is that `m_engine` is a dangling pointer.

That is, the memory pointed to by `m_engine` has been `delete`d.  You still have the address where the memory *was* allocated stored in `m_engine`, but when you try to access that address in memory expecting a valid `Foo`, `Bar`, etc. object to be there, that portion of memory has been reclaimed by the operating system and another object is possibly using that memory.

Accessing memory that has been deallocated is undefined behaviour in C++.

I suggest you add a breakpoints in the `m_engine` destructor (whatever the class is) to see who is deleting `m_engine`.

The other possibility is memory corruption, but this is much harder to diagnose.

Comment: Or, `m_engine` was never initialized, or it's a member of an object that's been deleted. (These are all versions of the same underlying problem, but to a newcomer it can be hard to see that.)

Comment: @Dan Breslau - if `m_engine` wasn't initialized, I would have thought it would have had a more predictable pattern like `0xcdcdcdcd` in it (although I'm making assumptions about compiler and OS).

Comment: That's a poor assumption; MS Studio is the only compiler I know of that initializes memory like that, and it only does that in when debug mode. But since we don't know the code, I'll add that it's possible that `m_engine` is accessed through a pointer that was initialized to something like 0xDEADBEEFBAADFOOD, which might point to memory that happens to have 0x2e6d763638667858 at that location. Unlikely, but possible.

Comment: Yes exactly right, I was doing some things out of order and trying to access the object before it was created.

Answer (score 0):

When the `this` pointer is 0x0, that means that you called a member function on a NULL pointer. You'll have to trace back through your code and figure out how the object pointer became NULL. There isn't enough in your sample code to diagnose the problem.

Comment: yes, and calling a member function with such a pointer is undefined behavior.

Comment: std::cout<<m_engine<<std::endl; focus_x = m_engine->getX(); The output is:0x2e6d763638667858 (not NULL), so that is not the problem...

Comment: @Chubsdad, undefined doesn't always mean unpredictable. Mainstream compilers often implement common constructs in the same fashion, and it is possible to guess and/or learn those internal workings.

Comment: @papodaca, that output is very suspect - why would an object be located at such a high address? Is `m_engine` a smart pointer or some other kind of object that emulates a pointer?

Comment: @Mark - unless `m_engine` is not a pointer, but an object with `operator<<` defined.  We don't really have enough information here.

Comment: @Chubsdad: no it isn't, it's only undefined if you actually use the this pointer (explicitly or implicitly). These semantics are in place because in some circumstances destructors need to do things like release OS resources after the object is destroyed. The issue arises because the question comes: can the compiler cache the this pointer in a register? Sorry I forget the actual examples which led to these rules, they're pretty weird but I've run into this myself.  A hint at the example is when you have an object paralleling an MS Windows Window, dtor has to be in order not rev order.